# How can I launch another application using the android_intent package?

Tags: flutter, android-intent

If I have a an app with package name com.example.firstapp, and a second app com.example.secondapp installed on the same device, how can I launch com.example.secondapp from com.example.firstapp using the android_intent package? What would be the correct values for the action, data, and, package fields of the AndroidIntent object?

Or in other words:  How can I use the android_intent package to launch another application by its package name?

Answer (score -1):

1. Add the following to `pubspec.yaml` under `dependencies`:

   ```
    device_apps:
    android_intent:
    url_launcher:
   ```
2. Add the following code:

   ```
    _openSecondApp(data) async {
        String dt = data['SecondApp'] as String;
        bool isInstalled = await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled('com.example.secondapp');

        if (isInstalled != false) {
            AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(action: 'action_view', data: dt);
            await intent.launch();
        } else {
            String url = dt;

            if (await canLaunch(url))
                await launch(url);
            else
                throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
    }
   ```